# how to solve a 4x5 matrix with guassian elimination or gaussian-jordan

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
3 &-3 &  1 & 5 & 8 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
I got the diagonal of leading 1s but only by making the bottom right number a large fraction.. and the answer in the solution are all small numbers without fractions.. I am not sure of a good method for doing 4x5, I tried doing the "forward" elimination to get the 0s under the diagonal.. but that just ended up in a large fraction on the bottom right.. im not sure how to attack this.. because it came out ugly...

here is my feeble soultion:

sitch R1 and R2

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
3 &-3 &  1 & 5 & 8 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

R2 = R2 - 2R1

R2 = -1 x R2

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & -13 \\
3 &-3 &  1 & 5 & 8 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

R3 += -3R1

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & -13 \\
0 &-3 & 7 & -16 & -25 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

R3 += 3R2

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & -13 \\
0 & 0 & -14 & 14 & -64 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

I actually can't figure out how I ever got any further than that...

EDIT: the very last 2 in the matrix was supposed to be a 10, but this doesnt change my solution thus far and I am still stuck... so if i could still have help please...

how can I change the first -14 into a 1?

Comment: Can you pls use Latex to format your question. Also, give an outline your solution.

Comment: i will try to add my feeble solution but im not sure how to use latex for this kinda problem

Comment: I have edited the matrix. Pls check/verify it. You might want to use this [quickref](http://users.dickinson.edu/~richesod/latex/latexcheatsheet.pdf) later.

Comment: Why don't you make the first entry of the third and fourth column zero as well in that step itself? $R_3 \to R_3 - 3R_1$ and $R_4 \to R_4 - 4R_1$.

Comment: i dont know, im just trying to do this step by step so i dont mess anything up on accident..

Comment: You already combined two steps by multiplying $R_2$ by $-1$ right after subtracting $2R_1$ from it. That's (slightly) worse than changing other rows using $R_1$. Don't apply more than one transformation to the same row in one step. But it's okay to apply transformations to multiple rows (independently) in the same step, and it's easy not to mess up doing this.

Comment: R2 conversion seems to have a calculation mistake, it should be 13, right?
The process you are following is correct. Pls go ahead and complete it.

Comment: which R2 conversion? and I think I'm stuck right here

Comment: im not sure how to get the -14 to turn into a 1. i need help with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
3 &-3 &  1 & 5 & 8 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{pmatrix} &\overset{2II-I}{\leadsto}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
3 &-3 &  1 & 5 & 8 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
&\overset{2III-3I}{\leadsto}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 &-3 &  -7 & -2 & -11 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
&\overset{IV -I}{\leadsto}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 &-3 &  -7 & -2 & -11 \\
0 & 2 &  1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
&\overset{III+3II}{\leadsto}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 & 0 &  -28 & 28 & 28 \\
0 & 2 &  1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
&\overset{IV -2II}{\leadsto}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 & 0 &  -28 & 28 & 28 \\
0 & 0 &  15 & -20 & -25 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
&\overset{28IV+15III}{\leadsto}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 & 0 &  -28 & 28 & 28 \\
0 & 0 &  0 & -140 & -280 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
&\overset{\frac{III}{28}, \frac{IV}{140}}{\leadsto}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 & 0 &  -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 &  0 & -1 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

Note that since the matrix multiplication is associative one can do any transformation when he wants, for example you could do the same step that i did in the opposite direction and get the same result, but to make it clearer i've wrote every single step. You can now solve the system just by evaluating the single components. Note that since your matrix has rang $4$ the solution is unique.

Does it help?

Comment: i cant really read the transformation symbols .. what did you do to the first one?

Comment: @JL  $I$ means *first row*,

$II$ means *second row* and so on. 

$2I - 3II$ means *two times the first row minus three times the second row*

does it help?

Comment: i see. i never thought of approaching it like that, and does there not need to be a leading 1 in the first row in order for the matrix to be in row echelon form?

Comment: @JL Yes, but writing a full solution would be long.

Comment: However when you evaluate the solution of your linear system you get automatically a $1$ on the leading index, indeed if you have this system

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & -1\\ 0 & 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Which is a linear system $Ax=b$ with $A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$, $x= \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}$ you get as solution 

$$x = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1-2}{2}= \frac{-3}{2} \\ \frac63 = 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

which is the same solution that you get by solving:

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac12 & \frac{-1}{2}\\ 0 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

with $A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac12 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and so on

Answer (score 2):

Jordan-Gauss elimination is convergent, meaning that however you proceed the normal form is unique. It is also always possible to reduce matrices of rank 4 (I assume yours is) to a normal form with the left 4x4 block being the identity, but the rightmost column cannot be reduced further. If your solution does not match the answer sheet, then you have made a computational error, which is frequent due to the sheer number of operations needed.

For a particular matrix, I could show you how I would reduce it, but I will let [your friend WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%5b%5b2%2C-1%2C3%2C4%2C9%5d%2C%5b1%2C0%2C-2%2C7%2C11%5d%2C%5b3%2C-3%2C1%2C5%2C8%5d%2C%5b2%2C1%2C4%2C4%2C10%5d%5d) do the comuputation, since this is faster and safer. If you have an account, you can see the procedure step-by-step.

**Edit:** WolframAlpha removed the free feature, but I will still use it for checking the work. You made a mistake too, but I corrected it. Now for the show:

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 & 0 & -14 & 14 & 8 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

$R_4 = R_4 + (-2)R_1$

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 & 0 & -14 & 14 & 8 \\
0 & 1 & 8 & -10 & -12 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

$R_4 = R_4 + (-1)R_2$

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 & 0 & -14 & 14 & 8 \\
0 & 0 & 15 & -20 & -25 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

$R_3 = R_3 + R_4$

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -6 & -17 \\
0 & 0 & 15 & -20 & -25 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

Now the 14 has disappeared. I will not write the rest because this is hard and long and I am not even sure I did not make mistakes, so you will want to check my work.

**Edit 2:** Actually, your corrected matrix is:

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 7 & 11 \\
0 & 1 & -7 & 10 & 13 \\
0 & 0 & -14 & 14 & 14 \\
2 & 1 &  4 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

You just have to divide by 14... I will leave the process above because the general "trick" has helped me when I did these sorts of exercises.

Comment: i can't afford an account though... and that computation is different than the one in my answers O_o.. wait... the very last number in the matrix was suppose to be 10... not 2... T_T *cries*

Comment: A free account still lets you see some solutions each day (my math friends use it constantly). Also, I updated the link.

Comment: it wont let me see this one, I just created an account and clicke show solution and it prompted for "pro" :(

Comment: I checked, and apparently they removed the free feature. Bummer. I will edit and write the solution from where you left your computation.

Comment: ok thannks ////

Comment: @JL You wanted to remove the 14, so I got up to that point. You should be able to continue from there.

Comment: I actually was working on that earlier, and got to the same point that was shown here. but then I tried getting rid of the 15 by taking -15R3 and adding it to R4, but that left me with 0 0 0 70 806 in the last row and that lead to a fraction for the last variable... and i thought that there had to be no fractions thus there being a computational error, so what is wrong with this?

Comment: First, have you corrected your error? The -13 should be a 13 in the second row. Second, sometimes row reduction produces fractions _while computing_ but the fractions magically simplify near the end. This is not necessarily an error, it is the result that counts.

Comment: i see that error i made, thanks. however if you add -15R3 to R4 you are left with 70z = 426 which results in a z value of 6.085 which doesnt match the book..

Comment: Oh snap, another miscalculation! Did I tell you I am so glad I don't do these exercises anymore?